# Do I need to compile the kernel again?

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules

Compile the kernel, and an option I forgot to give you my card support.
 Do I need to compile the kernel again?

```
$ Make && make modules_install
$ Make install
```

or is there an easier way to activate this feature and not compile everything again.

Comment: In the time it took for you to post this question, you probably could have just done the recompile. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `make && make modules_install` again.

It will only build those items that were added and other items that were affected by the change.